# Reset property in application delegate class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have following code in app delegate class

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    NSString *url;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *url;

@end
```

I initialised the url property in implement code.

Then in a view controller, I get the app delegate instance by:

```
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

But if I reset the url using `[appDelegate setUrl: nil],` it won't empty that property completely, I go another controller, it's still not empty.

Comment: Run the debugger an watch the value of url.

Answer (score 0):

The example you show should work just fine.
However, I suggest you to write a custom setter for the string in the app delegate. This way you will be able to see if your method get called.
You could also try sending a notification in order to change this app delegate property, and this will allow you to do that from anywhere in your app.